# Regression Analysis

Tags: r, regression, analysis

I am currently working on a project and I need some help. I want to predict the length of flight delays, using a statistical model. The data set does not contain the length of flight delays, but it can be calculated from the actual and scheduled departure times, I know that actual departure times - scheduled departure time will give me the flight delay which is the dependent variable. I am struggling to get the explanatory (independent) variables in a useful form to do regression analysis - the main problem is the time format of the first two columns when you read in the table from the csv file. I have attach the data file to the question because I wasn't too sure how to attach my file, I'm new to this coding thing hehe. Any help will be appreciated. xx

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11BXmJCB5UGEIRmVkM-yxPb_dHeD2CgXa/view?usp=sharing

EDIT:

Firstly Thank you for all the help

Okay I'm going to try and ask more precise questions on this topic:

So after importing the file using:

1)

```
    Delays <- read.table("FlightDelaysSM.csv",header =T,sep=",")
```

2)The main issue I am having is getting the columns schedule time and deptime into a format where I can do arithmetic calculation

3)I tried the below

```
    Delays[,1] - Delays[,2]
```

where the obvious issue arises for example 800 (8am) - 756 (7.56am) = 44 not 4 minutes

4)Using the help from @kerry Jackson (thank you, you're amazing x) I tried

```
    DepartureTime <- strptime(formatC(Delays$deptime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0", %H%M)

    ScheduleTime <- strptime(formatC(Delays$schedtime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0", %H%M)

    DelayTime = DepartureTime - ScheduleTime
```

The values are also given are in seconds, I want the difference to be in minutes how would I go about doing this?

5) I then did the following:

```
    DelayData <- data.frame(ScheduleTime, DepartureTime, DelayTime, Delays[, 4:7])
```

[What I attain after making the DelayData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAWkj.png)

as you can see by the image I have the seconds units in my column called DelayTime which I don't want as stated in 4), and the date is in the columns ScheduleTime and DepartureTime could I possibly get some suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: So what exactly did you try? Where are you getting stuck? Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input (in a reproducible format, not on an external site) and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the flight delay, perhaps you want to do something like `strptime(formatC(df$deptime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"), "%H%M") -  strptime(formatC(df$schedtime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"), "%H%M")`.

Comment: Thank you guys so much I have edited the question so it is hopefully more clear on what i'm stuck on.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new column called `flight_delay`:

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)

your_data <- your_data %>%
  mutate(flight_delay=deptime-schedtime)
```

Now, create a linear regression model predicting `flight_delay` by every other variable:

```
mod <- lm(flight_delay ~ ., data=your_data)
```

To optimize your model, use the `step` function:

```
mod <- step(mod)
```

Analyze results:

```
summary(mod)
```

Comment: This doesn't calculate the flight_delay correctly because the time is in hours and minutes, not just minutes.

Comment: You can use the truncate function within the `mutate` to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you guys so much x